# I am not able to insert the data into database mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to input these values into database but everytime there is an error. I think the error is in this part of code but i am not able to find it plzz help.

```
<?php

    if ($roomtype == "DeluxeRoom")
        {
        $rom = "SELECT room_id FROM room WHERE room_id NOT IN ( SELECT room_id 
        FROM reservation WHERE start_date <= '2016-02-27' AND end_date >= '2016-02-
        24')";
        }
?>
```

---

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'database.php';

if (isset($_POST['signup']))
    {
    $checkin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['checkin']);
    $checkout = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['checkout']);
    $numroom = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['numroom']);
    $roomtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['roomtype']);
    $cid = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
    if ($roomtype == "DeluxeRoom")
        {
        $rom = "SELECT room_id FROM room WHERE room_id NOT IN ( SELECT room_id 
    FROM reservation WHERE start_date <= '2016-02-27' AND end_date >= '2016-02-
    24')";
        }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO reservation (customer_id,room_id,start_date, end_date) 
    VALUES('" . $cid . "','" . $rom . "','" . $checkin . "','" . $checkout . "')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Error";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can you also share the error that you encountered?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Try changing the start date and end date swap them...

Comment: Also never concatenate strings for SQL. Learn to use parameters in queries from the beginning. They will remove a lot of problems and enhance security a lot.

Comment: If you echo the query, one error should be fairly obvious.

Comment: When i click on submit button, it shows me ''Error"  which i have written in the code

Comment: If your $roomtype is not "DeluxeRoom", the $rom variable does not have value

Comment: Try this and share error:
`if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {echo "New record created successfully"; } else {  echo "Error:" . mysqli_error($con);   }`

Comment: So many problems here.  First of all, [use PDO and prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  Next, check your `$sql` in the case when `$roomtype` *is* `DeluxeRoom` - instead of a room_id you've got a big long `SELECT` string. And finally, use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKPG9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKPG9.png) This is my opinion. And I think that the statement is not worng.

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert `$rom` in `INSERT` query. You must serialize it value to string:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'database.php';
?>
<?php


if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
$checkin  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['checkin']);
$checkout = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['checkout']);
$numroom = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['numroom']);
$roomtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['roomtype']);
$cid=$_SESSION['usr_id'];

if($roomtype=="DeluxeRoom")
{
    $rom="SELECT room_id FROM room WHERE room_id NOT IN ( SELECT room_id 
FROM reservation WHERE start_date <= '2016-02-27' AND end_date >= '2016-02-
24')";
}
$q = mysqli_query($con, $rom);
$row = json_encode($q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM));


$sql="INSERT INTO reservation (customer_id,room_id,start_date, end_date) 
VALUES('" . $cid . "','" . $rom . "','" . $checkin . "','" . $checkout . 
"')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing the query built in $rom. Also, as Sami Kuhmonen pointed out, you really should use prepared statements instead of string concatenation.

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'database.php';

if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
    $checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
    $numroom = $_POST['numroom'];
    $roomtype = $_POST['roomtype'];
    $cid = $_SESSION['usr_id'];

    if ($roomtype == "DeluxeRoom") {
        if (($res = mysqli_query(
                $con,
                "SELECT room_id FROM room WHERE room_id NOT IN ( SELECT room_id
FROM reservation WHERE start_date <= '2016-02-27' AND end_date >= '2016-02-
24')"
            )) !== false) {
            list($rom) = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
        }
    }

    $statement = mysqli_prepare(
        $con,
        "INSERT INTO reservation (customer_id,room_id,start_date, end_date)
VALUES(?,?,?,?)"
    );
    if ($statement === false) {
        die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $statement->bind_param('ssss', $cid, $rom, $checkin, $checkout);
    if ($statement->execute()) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have been able to do the select and i am getting 5 values(row) and i want to insert only the first value. How to do it?

if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
$checkin  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['checkin']);
$checkout = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['checkout']);
$numroom = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['numroom']);
$roomtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['roomtype']);
$cid=$_SESSION['usr_id'];

if($roomtype=="DeluxeRoom")
{
    $rom="SELECT room_id FROM room WHERE roomtype='DeluxeRoom' AND room_id 
 NOT IN ( SELECT room_id FROM reservation WHERE start_date <= '2016-02-27' 
 AND 
 end_date >= '2016-02-24')";
 }

$result = mysqli_query($con, $rom);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["room_id"]. " <br>"; 
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
    }


$sql="INSERT INTO reservation (customer_id,room_id,start_date, end_date) 
VALUES('" . $cid . "','" . $row["room_id"] . "','" . $checkin . "','" . 
$checkout . "')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error";
}
}
```